# Can $\operatorname{rank}_km/m^2-\dim A$ become arbitrary large?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

For a Noether local ring $A$ with maximal ideal $m$, we can define the embedding dimension of $A$ by $\operatorname{rank}_km/m^2$.

In general, $\dim A\leq \operatorname{rank}_km/m^2$ holds, but the equality does not hold in general. ($A$ is called regular local ring if only if the equality holds).

Then my question

> Can $\operatorname{rank}_km/m^2-\dim A$ become arbitrary large ?

Maybe there are geometrical intuitive interpretation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ring $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_p]/\langle (x_i x_j)_{1\leq i<j\leq p}\rangle$. Let $A$ be its localisation at the maximal ideal $m=\langle x_1,\dots,x_p\rangle$.

Since the associated scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is the union of the axes through the origin in $\mathbb{A}^p$, it is clear that the embedding dimension is $p$. On the other hand the ring has dimension $1$.

Comment: Could you tell me why Spec($R$) is union of axes through the origin in $A^p$ means $A$'s embedding dimension is $p$?

Comment: One just calculates $m/m^2$ which is $p$-dimensional. By the way, one can give an even easier example by taking $A=k\oplus V$ where elements of $V$ are nilpotent of order $2$. In this case $m/m^2=V$.

Comment: Even your example can be slightly changed in order to be simpler: write $i\le j$ instead of $i<j$. Then $m^2=0$, and the dimension of $A$ is obviously zero. As it is now you left the OP struggling with $\dim A$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284834

Comment: This has the added benefit of not requiring one to localize as $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1,\dots,x_n)^2$ is already local.

Comment: @user26857 and metalspringpro There could be refinements of the above asking for a reduced ring $A$ or even $A$ a domain! So, the given answer points to that general direction. I agree that the 0-dimensional case is the easiest for the original question.